# Javascript toggle class not working?

Tags: javascript, class, toggle, this, buttonclick

```
$('.form-control').on('focus blur', function (e) {
    $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
}).trigger('blur');

$('#moveleft').click(function () {
    $('#textbox').animate({
        'marginLeft': "0" //moves left
    });
    $('.toplam').animate({
        'marginLeft': "100%" //moves right
    });
});

$('#moveright').click(function () {
    $('#textbox').animate({
        'marginLeft': "50%" //moves right
    });
    $('.toplam').animate({
        'marginLeft': "0" //moves right
    });
});
```

Comment: where is the html sample

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to the event "focus blur"  which does not exist.

It is either `.on("focus", function(e) { });`

or it is  `.on("blur", function(e) { } );`

https://jsfiddle.net/kt0sswfh/